# Highlight letter under the cursor as a part of selectin in Vim's visual mode

Tags: vim, highlighting

I'm using console Vim in gnome-terminal and I'd like to highlight the letter under the cursor in Visual mode to look like a part of the selection (which it is in fact).

The `:h hl-cursor` thing does not work for me (I mean using this highlight mode described on that help page) -- `:highlight Cursor ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=Green` does not seem to change anything. The `:set t_cv=^[^[ t_ci=^[^[` from `:h visual` does not do anything too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how you can solve your very problem but I suggest you to try:

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntaxt/hitest.vim
```

You'll like its output :)